# Publish sensor data to cartographer

Tags: c++, publish, sensors, ros, point-clouds

I'm working with google cartographer and I have a rgb camera. I have a topic where the PointCloud2 data is published to. It's /ifm3d/camera/cloud and I made my own node to publish this data to the cartographer. The cartographer has a topic where points2 is subscribing to. But my problem is that I don't know how to write the code to publish the sensor data to the cartographer. This is my code:

```
...
ros::init(argc,argv,"point_cloud_publisher);
ros::NodeHandle nh;

ros::Publisher pub_pointCloud = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud>("/points2",1000); 
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
```

So I have a camera and its publishing its data to the topic and I don''t know how to publish it to the cartographer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the subscriber. In order to publish the data from your camera to cartographer, your node needs to subscribe to the data first.

Take a look at the [ROSCPP Publisher/Subscriber Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) first and try to implement a simple example. Your code should contain:

1) A **subscriber** that subscribes to the topic `/ifm3d/camera/cloud`

> ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/ifm3d/camera/cloud", 1000, callback);

2) A **callback function** that does something with the data received by the subscriber

3) A **publisher** that publishes the data you've received from the subscriber (you've set this up already)

Looks like you intended to use `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;` as the cloud you want to publish. Simply assign the values you receive from the subscriber to this variable, inside the callback function, then call on your publisher using:

> pub_pointCloud.publish(cloud);